# snap doesn't install Firefox, snap core20: Now No such file or directory

Tags: unity, firefox, snap, hunspell

Ubuntu 22.04 with fresh updates. I have free space on the disk. I tried to remove Firefox and install it again. There are a lot problems with the Firefox snap, so I installed from Mozilla. Snap is not use full. How create to a config file for something using snap?

```
sudo snap install firefox
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Copy snap "firefox" data (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_GB.aff: read-only file system)
- Run hook connect-plug-host-hunspell of snap "firefox" (run hook "connect-plug-host-hunspell": cannot locate base snap core20: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Please add some details. Version of Ubuntu? What is this data you are trying to copy?

Comment: Workaround: Use firefox without snap. Also, it would consume less disk space, will be faster if you don't have an SSD, and will integrate better with other native apps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)